# Expression Blend 4 Patches

Tags: expression-blend

Where can I get the list of patches/service packs for Expression Blend 4?

Comment: I put your question into google exactly  as you typed it above and the first result was this: http://www.microsoft.com/expression/service-packs/Blend.aspx

Comment: Don't be snide. I get "french patch pour Microsoft Expression Blend" as the top result.

Answer (score 0):

Service Pack 1 for Expression Blend 4 is currently out.

http://www.microsoft.com/expression/service-packs/Blend.aspx